# Recorrer array para insertar resultados en consulta en MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

saludos a todos, tengo el siguiente código:

```
$marca1 = $_GET['marca1'];
    if (is_array($marca1))
    {
      for ($y=0;$y<count($marca1);$y++){
      }
    }

$sql="SELECT * FROM `jsonBuscador` WHERE `categoria` = 'BOCINAS' AND `tags` LIKE '%$marca1[0]%' LIMIT $TAMANO_PAGINA OFFSET $offset";
```

Estoy intentando insertar el valor de 'marca1' dentro de una consulta en Mysql, sin embargo no puedo determinar cual es el mejor modo de hacerlo, les comento, los valores llegan desde un formulario en el cual los valores a seleccionar provienen de un checkbox, como son varios, he creado el arreglo en HTML de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class='widget widget_recent_posts'>
      <h3 class='widget-title'>MOSTRAR RESULTADOS POR:</h3>
      <form class='commerce-ordering' style='float: none !important;' action='bocinas1.php' method='get'>
        <p style='color:#000;font-weight: bold;'>MARCA</p>
        <div class='form-check'>
          <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='marca1[]' id='marca1' value='PEAVEY'>
          <label class='form-check-label' for='gridCheck1'>SAMPLE</label>
          <img src='http://electronica2001es.com/img/2020/peavey.png' style='width: 25%;'></div>
        <div class='form-check'>
          <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='marca1[]' id='marca2' value='DAS'>
          <label class='form-check-label' for='gridCheck1'>SAMPLE</label>
          <img src='http://electronica2001es.com/img/2020/das.png' style='width: 50%;'></div>
        <div class='form-check'>
          <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='marca1[]' id='marca3' value='SOUNDBARRIER'>
          <label class='form-check-label' for='gridCheck1'>SAMPLE</label>
          <img src='http://electronica2001es.com/img/2020/barrier.png' style='width: 50%;'> </div>
        <div class='form-check'>
```

Agradecería que me pudieran ayudar a salir de la duda, saludos.

Comment: y que recibes en $_GET['marca1'] ya comprobaste que es un array y no un string??? haste un output de esa variable y agrégala a tu post

Comment: Efectivamente, he realizado el output en mi código y puedo afirmar que se devuelve un array.

Comment: ¿Con qué código intentas el INSERT? En la pregunta muestras un SELECT. ¿Hay errores? ¿Qué errores?

Comment: El INSERT se hace usando el primer código, el SELECT únicamente es para crear el arreglo desde donde traigo los datos.

Comment: ¿Acaso el problema no es que no puedes hacer el INSERT? Entonces tienes que poner en la pregunta el código que estás usando para verificarlo. Dinos también qué has depurado y con qué resultados y si tienes errores. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Hola basado en el código php que colocaste te muestro como se recorre el Array... Y como lo con catenaria yo en la consulta... Si es un `SELECT ` o un  `insert `  lo único que tienes que hacer es modificar el string y concatenar $vale donde quieras

Comment: Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería ser asi:

Más o menos no se de donde sale `$TAMANO_PAGINA` ni el `$offset`

```php
$marca1 = $_GET['marca1']; 
$sql.='';
if (is_array($marca1)) { 
    foreach ($marca1 as $key => $value){ 
        $sql.="SELECT * FROM jsonBuscador WHERE categoria= 'BOCINAS' AND tags LIKE '%". $vale."%' LIMIT ".$TAMANO_PAGINA." OFFSET ".$offset.";";
    } 
} 

echo $sql;
```

basado en el código `php` que colocaste te muestro como se recorre el `Array`... Y como lo con catenaria en la consulta... Si es un `SELECT`  o un  `INSERT`  lo único que tienes que hacer es modificar el `string` y concatenar `$vale` donde quieras.